Predictable seasons on an interlunar system
My goal is to add stable seasons to the Moons 1-4 I've created. Basically the Gas Giant and the 4 depicted moons should have the same seasonal cycle. Just because it think its easier and it makes sense given the tidally locked orbits


The moon orbits a gas giant at a distance of 2.7 AU from a 1.1 solar mass star.
The moon will be shielded by the planet once each lunar orbit. However, it won't affect the entire area of the surface which is exposed to the primary.
Masses of the moons: 1: 50%, 2: 60%, 3: 60%, 4: 80% of Earth.
Distance between Moons 2 and 3: 250'000 km
Distance between Moons 4 and 3: 650'000 km
Distance between moon 3 and the gas giant is 900000 km.
The gas giant possesses 12 Jupiter masses.
All the depicted moons are tidally locked to their primary.
All the moons orbit around the gas giant's equatorial plane with 0 Inclination.
One orbit around the gas giant takes 38 hours. Since it is tidally locked,that's equal to a day, not a "year" on this moon obviously.
The Gas giant takes 4 years to orbit it's star, but this on its own has no influence on the temperature on the moon, since the planet's orbit since:
All the orbits are nearly circular.

For a predictable pattern of seasons, the axial tilt of the moon needs to be stabilized.
I am imagining a setup like this:

The Equatorial plane of the Gas giant is the same as the satellite's equatorial plane.
The Rotational Axis of both planet and moons have the same alignment and obliquity.
Because of this, the equatorial plane of both Planet and Satellites have 2 yearly maximum deviations relative to the solar equatorial plane.

What factors or physical properties of moons and planet could lead to a stabilization of the axis and its maximum tilt in the moons around this gas giant and ensure predictable and somewhat stable seasons? My goal is to have tropical circles between 20 and 30 degrees, and having the seasons not longer than maybe 4 times compared to earth.

Finally, a question: you don't have a planet orbiting a star, you have a planetoid orbiting a planet orbiting a star. Calling the orbit of the child around its parent a "year," the year of your moon isn't at all equivalent to the year of the gas giant. Your seasons will always be chaotic to a degree regardless the axial tilt of the moon. You don't need to be tidally locked to have an axial tilt of zero (which would help minimize the chaos) and zero lunar orbit eccentricity and obliquity will also help. But still... Therefore, what exactly do you mean by "stable?"

Note that I removed the [tag:internal-consistency] tag. You didn't read its wiki. That tag has a very specific purpose and posts must conform to specific rules, none of which you've done. It's purpose is to test a worldbuilding rule to be sure the OP is using it consistently. It is not a "reality check."

by "stable" i mean that we have a certain, returning pattern of seasons and not having the polar area suddenly exposed to amounts of sunlight only known by the equatorial regions.

OK, when it comes to climate "stable" and "predictable" are very different things. I recommend you [edit] your post to change "stable" to "predictable." But before you do, think through what you really need here. Unless that moon is wobbling around randomly, you will always have predictable weather patterns (insofar as humans understand "predictable" today, meteorologists are still notoriously inaccurate). So you're going to have predictable weather as-is, the question is what is it doing?

One last thing to remember: questions about climate are the most difficult questions to answer on this site. Climate is horrendously, stupendously, even irreverently complex. Humanity is still having trouble predicting what local weather will do tomorrow (yeah, I just said that), so asking us what's going to happen on your fictional moon that's pretty much nothing like Earth is a tough request. Again, think about what your problem really is because the more specific you can make this question, the more likely you'll get useful answers.

I think my problem can be described best by saying: On the world I'm designing my goal is to have a climate with a similar degree of stability and predictability like on earth. Sure there will be natural changes, like on earth, but preferably not more than on earth.
My goal is to be able to formulate some thesis, like an educated guess, on how the climate might be, as exactly as possible. that's why I'm willing to keep improving this question as much as i need to.

By predictability i mean: Long-Term-Predictability. A  cycle of re-ocurring seasons that enables life to adapt to, rather than a total chaos. Even though weather and climate on earth include some degree of unpredictability, we can still say: We will have the same 4 seasons next year, like the years before. (Even more so without man made climate change)

@JBH I don't see why the moon orbiting the gas giant has seasons influenced by its orbit and the gas giant. The gas giants seasons are influenced by its racial tilt, as are the moon's, but the moon's seasons won't be affected by the gas giant. The only way I can see is to have the gas giant orbit elliptically, but that isn't likely to last. What am I missing?

@Bubbles I didn't say that, I pointed out that what a "season" is on such a moon will be more chaotic due to its relationship with the gas giant. Simplifying horrendously, the moon is hidden from the sun for half of the gas giant's year around its sun. Our moon wobbles a bit - does Ben's moon? Our moon moves further/closer to Earth over time, does Ben's moon? Moon climates are ugly complex because we have no examples for reference. We're all guessing - which is good for a worldbuilder unless they're stuck on trying to make everything "scientifically" perfect. ... (*Continued*)

... What we really have here is an opportunity to use what we know about moons to play "what if?" games - which is excellent worldbuilding.

@Ben I'm grateful for the clarifications, but please remember to [edit] your post to include them. It's a good habit to never trust that anyone will read comments. Cheers!

@JBH Fair enough, I was just a bit confused.

@JBH: "The moon is hidden from the sun for half of the gas giant's year around its sun": No it is not. At most, two times per year the satellite will be in the shadow of the planet for about 5 hours out of its 19 hours daytime.

@AlexP I did say "simplifying horrendously," but 25% vs. 50% is simply semantics. That's a lot of cool-off time compared to a planet that experiences solar energy 100% of the time.

@JBH: Yes, but it is only two times per year, for a few days. In the vast majority of the time the satellite is never in the shadow on the gas giant, because the question says that the orbit is inclined 20 or 30 degrees with respect of the orbital plane of the primary.

@AlexP That's not what the question states, but it recently changed. In its current form, the lunar orbit has a zero-degree inclination with a goal of "tropical circles between 20 and 30 degrees."

@JBH: The tropic circles are located at the latitudes equal to the obliquity of the axis of rotation with respect to the ecliptic. If the tropic circles are "between 20 and 30 degrees" then the axis of rotation is tilted 20 to 30 degrees with respect to the ecliptic. Since the axis of rotation is given as being not tilted with respect to the orbital plane of the satellite, this means that the orbital plane of the satellite itself is inclined 20 to 30 degrees with respect to the orbital plane of the gas giant. As illustrated in the picture.

@AlexP I'm just pointing out a statement the OP has made: "The moon orbits on the gas giant's equatorial plane with 0 Inclination." The picture shows the gas giant has an axial tilt, but the OP doesn't state what it is. The question concerning 20-30 degrees doesn't appear to be related to inclination or obliquity - it appears to be relevant to the location of the tropics (of cancer and capricorn, as it were). If the picture is what we're working with, then Moon #3 never rises above the parallel of the giant to its sun, so the obliquity might as well be zero.

@JBH: Equatorial plane, not ecliptic plane. The axis of rotation of the gas giant itself is tilted with respect with the ecliptic plane. The OP wants to have the satellite share the same seasons as the primary for some reason.

@AlexP Yes, I got that. But as drawn the moon will be shielded by the planet once each lunar orbit, not twice each planetary orbit. This would be a great clarificaiton from the OP, but to make a point, no matter how the moon orbits the gas giant, it won't have seasons equal to the gas giant. This is a fairly complex question (not that questions about climate are ever simple).

@Ben can you add the distances and masses of the other 3 moons? they could be important in influencing both the orbit of moon 3 and possibly geologic or climate events. Also based on the values you've given it should be clarified that the distance from the CENTER of the moon to the CENTER of the gas giant is 900000 km, not the distance between surfaces. given how large your gas giant is (~160000 km radius) that cuts out a not insignificant chunk of that distance and impacts energy returned from albedo.

Yes. The moon is, according to my simulation, shielded once per orbit around the gas giant. The Gas Giant's Shadow's Position varies depending on the season or the current axial alignment.
Also yes, i want my moon to have tropics. These should be located between the cancer and capricorn equivalents. roughly at the same latitudes like earth. Due to the gas giant's presence, they are different than on earth of course.

The most striking effect of the seasons will be differences in illumination.
These moons are small and very cold (Assuming Earthlike albedo, which I probably can't, 260K * (1.1 / 2.7^2)^0.25 = 150K equilibrium temperature).  The gas giant they orbit may warm them a little, depending on how much internal heat it is releasing.  This is warm enough to support an atmosphere, but -120 C is much too cold for liquid water.  We know from the case of Titan that we can't rule out some opaque atmosphere that will confuse all I'm about to say, and sufficient winds will at least average out the effects.  The matchup between the gas giant's reflected light and radiated heat, and the greenhouse properties of the moon's atmosphere, may need to be considered.
The part of the moons facing away from the gas giant will be colder, and experience the seasons much as if it were a separate planet of that size and temperature.
The part of the moons facing the planet may be warmer.  At spring and fall (all seasons are relative to the gas giant's orbital period), this part of the moons will get the most exposure to the equatorial part of the gas giant.  At other times it will be exposed to more temperate areas.  This could tend to make winter colder than the variation of the other three seasons would lead you to expect.  In any case, daily exposure of the moon to the lit and dark side of the gas giant, as well as its constant heat, may tend to even out the seasons.
The most notable change is that during summer the gas giant's sunlit pole will be visible from the nearside of the moons while they are eclipsed behind it, bringing light to that otherwise dark time of (lunar) "day".  They will conversely have less light from the gas giant at lunar "night" when they cannot see the sun but see most of the gas giant lit up.
The second most notable change is that if the orbits are not perfectly circular, then there is libration, bringing the gas giant into view for part of the moon's orbit for portions near the boundary of the near and far side.

Yes, the Moon librates $\rightarrow$as seen from Earth$\leftarrow$. It is an apparent movement, it is not very large, and it is cyclical anyway. Basically, there are two components:

The libration in longitude (lunar east and west) reaches an amplitude about 7°54′ and is due to the fact that the orbit of the Moon is not a perfect circle, but rather an ellipse with an eccentricity of about 0.055. (This is three times as large as the eccentricity of Earth's orbit around the sun.)
Because the orbit is not perfectly circular, while the rotation of the Moon around its axis is obviously almost perfectly regular, there are times when the rotation is a little ahead of the orbital position, and times when it is a little behind.

The libration in latitude (lunar north and south) reaches an amplitude of about 6°50′ and is due to the tilt of the axis of rotation of the satellite with respect to its own orbital plane plus the inclination of the orbit with respect to the ecliptic.


Again this is all an apparent motion as seen from Earth.
I don't know what makes you believe that the Moon had a significantly different axis of rotation is any reasonable time period, such as the last few tens of millions of years.
Note that the axial tilt of Earth itself varies in time, not all that much, but still noticeable, between about 22° and 24° 20′; it currently is about 23° 26′. This happens on time scales measured in millions of years.
When speaking of the axial tilt of a satellite you must be aware that you want to know three different values:

The tilt of the axis of rotation of the satellite with respect to its own orbital plane. In the case of our dear Moon, this is 6° 41′.

The tilt of the axis of rotation of the satellite with respect to the equatorial plane of its primary. In the case of our dear Moon, this is 24°.

The tilt of the axis of rotation of the satellite with respect to the orbital plane plane of its primary, also known as the ecliptic. In the case of our dear Moon, this is 1° 33′.
This is the number which counts when considering the seasons; it is the algebric sum of the tilt of the axis of rotation of the satellite with respect to its own orbital plane, and the inclination of the orbit with respect to the ecliptic. (The orbit of our Moon is inclined 5° 9′ with respect to Earth's orbital plane.)



Thank you for the answer so far. Today and yesterday I've been busy otherwise, but later I will properly edit the question, and add an illustration to further clarify what my goals are.

@Ben: You should explain why you believe that the orbital plane and the axis of rotation of the satellite would be varying greatly on any kind of reasonable timespan. That is to say, why is it that you believe that some sort of special stabilization is necessary.

I am not sure. Maybe I just confused some terms. So could I expect that without any other massive body close to the gas giant, the setup depicted in my illustration would just happen after the formation of those moons, caused by the tidal locking?

@Ben: Look at the four Galilean satellites of Jupiter. Their orbits are very slightly inclined with respect to the equatorial plane of Jupiter, with the largest inclination being the half degree of Europa. Their axial tilts are all less than one third of a degree.

I see. Thank you for the answer. So I'm assuming that my illustration is correct.
